# If input or div is disabled then add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple contact form and I have the submit input disabled until all inputs have at least some text.

**Problem:** The issue with this is that I have classes assigned to this submit input, hover/active & regular; and so even tho it's disabled it looks like it's not because the hover state still works as well as the regular class.

**Question:** Can I add a class to my submit input by telling it to add a class if disabled? How can I go about this? I'm new to JS/jQuery.

***My Code below:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $submit = $("input[type=submit]"),
    $inputs = $('input[type=text], input[type=email]');

  function checkEmpty() {
    return $inputs.filter(function() {
      return !$.trim(this.value);
    }).length === 0;
  }
  $inputs.on('blur', function() {
    $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
  }).blur();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.contact_btn {
  background-color: #FC354C;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 7px 42px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 7px 42px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 7px 42px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.contact_btn:hover {
  background-color: #fc4f63;
}
.contact_btn:active {
  background-color: #fb0421;
  -moz-transform: scale3d(0.94, 0.94, 0.94);
  -ms-transform: scale3d(0.94, 0.94, 0.94);
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.94, 0.94, 0.94);
  transform: scale3d(0.94, 0.94, 0.94);
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 18px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 18px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 18px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="name_in" type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Name*" required>
  <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="Email*" required>
  <input name="telephone" pattern="^[0-9\-\+\s\(\)]*$" placeholder="Phone">
  <input class="contact_btn" type="submit" value="Send Your Message">
</form>
```

Comment: it's not valid for a `<div>` to have a `disabled` attribute. On `<input>`s, you can use a CSS selector `"input[disabled]"`.

Comment: Also yes its possible. You can try `var el = $(element); el.toggleClass('className', el.is(":disabled"))`

Comment: you can use jquery addClass() function on submit button, $submit.addClass()

Comment: @toastal Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For Removing hover effect while it is disable, change your css code to like this `.button:hover::enabled`. it only applicable when button is enabled. but IE<9 does not support it

```
.contact_btn:hover:enabled{
   /* this will only show when the button is enabled, */
   /* and the user is hovering over it.. */
}
```